# What actually are the transfer functions in filtfilt (Matlab's zero-offset filter)?

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm trying to adapt some code that generates a daily-mean time series from an input of 6-hourly-means, to instead use data with 1-hourly-means. The way it appears to do this is by using Matlab's `filtfilt` function with `b=[0.5 1 1 1 0.5]/4` and `a=[1 0 0 0 0]`, which are apparently the filter transfer functions. The problem is that I have absolutely no idea what a filter transfer function is (and most explanations I've found require an engineering background that I do not have), and I'm therefore not sure how to adapt this filter to instead use 1-hourly-means.

Naively, since the 6-hourly-mean time series has 4 data points per day, I'm wondering if this is the reason why the numbers in `b` add up to 4, and since I now have 24 data points per day, if the values I need are therefore:

`b=[0.5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0.5]`

`a=[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

But I'm really not sure!

Answer (score 1):

when `a = 1`, `filter` simply apply a convolution (in one direction) and `filtfilt` apply a convolution in both direction (forward and then backward).

So `filtfilt` is nothing more than a convolution in both direction, here is the example of a 1D continuous convolution in forward direction.

[image]

*source : Wikipedia, animation by Lautaro Carmona*

So for example:

```
close all
% make the example reproductible
rng('default')
% random vector
x = rand(72,1); 

% a, the trailing zero are totally useless.
a = 1; 
% b
b = [0.5 1 1 1 0.5];
% filtfilt
Xfilt = filtfilt(b/4,a,x);
% forward and then backward convolution
Xconv = fliplr(conv(fliplr(conv(x,b/4,'same')),b/4,'same'));

% plot the result
hold on
plot(Xfilt)
plot(Xconv)
legend('filtfilt','convolution')
```

Output this figure:

[image]

The convolution and the filtfilt function output, as expected, the same values (except for the boundary, because `filtfilt` compensate the boundary effect).

you can even obtain the exact same result if you also compensate the boundary effect.

It become clear now that we have to divide `b` by `sum(b)` to apply a moving average.

So, indeed, if you need to apply your moving average to take into account the past 12 values and the next 12 values your b vector should be `[0.5 ones(1,23) 0.5]`.